# SAS: Importing Fixed Width file w Infile function and where clause

Tags: file-io, sas

I have two SAS data steps that import a text file called "Provider_Master.txt" using a fixed Width approach.  The first data step pulls the entire "Provider_Master.txt" file into SAS as a dataset called "t_Pvdr_Mstr" and the next data step retains only the parts of the file that I need, which is RecordTypes that have a "T" in the RecordType field. This approach works well enough but is very inefficient because the file is over 2 gigs large.  Once I strip away all the lines that don't have a "T" the RecordTypes field, the file is less than 400 KBs. It would make alot more sense to only import the lines I need instead of importing the entire text file but I'm not sure how to contrain the import to only pull down RecordTypes that have a "T".  Below is an example of the code I'm currently using....

```
data Grid.t_Pvdr_Mstr ;
infile "C:\SASData\Provider_Master.txt " truncover;
    input
    Insurer $ 1-4
    RecordType $ 5-7
    Actions $ 8-8
    Pvdr $ 9-18
    Type $ 19-19
    Name $ 20-58
    Bus_Type_Code $ 59-61
    Bus_Date $ 62-69
    Address1 $ 70-129
    Address2 $ 130-189
    City $ 190-219
    State $ 220-221
    Zip $ 222-230
    County $ 231-260
    Country $ 261-263
    Phone $ 264-274;
run;

data Grid.t_Pvdr_Mstr;
set Grid.t_Pvdr_Mstr;
where RecordType = 'T';
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `if` statement to prevent it from outputting unneeded records. That way you do not need to create a second step with a `where` statement.

```
data Grid.t_Pvdr_Mstr ;
infile "C:\SASData\Provider_Master.txt " truncover;
    input
    Insurer $ 1-4
    RecordType $ 5-7
    Actions $ 8-8
    Pvdr $ 9-18
    Type $ 19-19
    Name $ 20-58
    Bus_Type_Code $ 59-61
    Bus_Date $ 62-69
    Address1 $ 70-129
    Address2 $ 130-189
    City $ 190-219
    State $ 220-221
    Zip $ 222-230
    County $ 231-260
    Country $ 261-263
    Phone $ 264-274;

    if(RecordType = 'T');
run;
```

An `if` without `then` statement effectively says "Do not pass this line unless this is true." Since `output` is implied at the `run` boundary, we're only outputting records where `RecordType = 'T'`.

Comment: I am happy to hear that it helped. Please consider marking this as accepted so that others can quickly find the answer as well.